# Query with using max-width in relative units for Flexbox display

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to display 4 photos and biography of team members in a row to fit wrapper container using display flex. It works when I use max-width for each img to 360px but does not work when I use max-width in % relative unit. Anyone know why? I want to use relative units in all my projects and I just can't wrap my head around this.

```
<div id="people">

                    <div class="john person">
                        <img src="images/john%20doe.jpg" alt="CEO">
                        <h3>John Doe</h3>
                        <h4>CEO & Founder</h4>
                        <button>Contact</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="jane person">
                        <img src="images/jane%20doe.jpg" alt="architect">
                        <h3>Jane Doe</h3>
                        <h4>Architect</h4>
                        <button>Contact</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mike person">
                        <img src="images/mike%20ross.jpg" alt="architect">
                        <h3>Mike Ross</h3>
                        <h4>Architect</h4>
                        <button>Contact</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="dan person">
                        <img src="images/dan%20star.jpg" alt="architect">
                        <h3>Dan Star</h3>
                        <h4>Architect</h4>
                        <button>Contact</button>
                    </div>            

                </div>


    #people{
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-basis:100%;
    }

   #people div img {
        max-width: 360px;
    }
```

The above code achieves the results. But if I want to change max width in #people div img {} to a relative % unit, does anyone know how I do this. I am using an online template and trying to reconstruct it myself (hence I'm asking, if I had to create something like this myself for a real project I wouldn't understand this issue). Thanks!

Comment: Provide a working code snippet that reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were referring to this. You need to add the property of `flex:1;` to `#people` child classes i.e `.person`, thus making it flexible (flex-grow:1, flex-shrink:1, flex-basis:auto). And then set the width of the image to `100%` which will resize relative to the viewport width.

```css
#people {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.person{
flex:1;
}

.person img {
max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="people">

  <div class="john person">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="CEO">
    <h3>John Doe</h3>
    <h4>CEO & Founder</h4>
    <button>Contact</button>
  </div>

  <div class="jane person">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="architect">
    <h3>Jane Doe</h3>
    <h4>Architect</h4>
    <button>Contact</button>
  </div>

  <div class="mike person">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="architect">
    <h3>Mike Ross</h3>
    <h4>Architect</h4>
    <button>Contact</button>
  </div>

  <div class="dan person">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="architect">
    <h3>Dan Star</h3>
    <h4>Architect</h4>
    <button>Contact</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @user8322222 No, problem mate. Mark the answer up if it did. Cheers